# load an external .jsp page in fancybox

Tags: jquery, jsp, fancybox

I am trying to load an external page in Fancybox, but am just getting a blank iframe.

if I try `<dsp:include page="/jsp/product/us/common/accoladeDisplay.jsp"/>` on the .jsp I am trying to load from the page loads fine. Fancybox doesn't seem to like me using `<a href="/jsp/product/us/common/accoladeDisplay.jsp" class="has-award-popup">more info</a></p>`.

Here's the .js:

```
if($("a.has-award-popup").length > 0){
    $(".has-award-popup").fancybox({
        'width'             : '50%',
        'height'            : '75%',
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });

}
```

Comment: Your jQuery code above doesn't launch fancybox ... only binds fancybox to the selector `.has-award-popup` IF it meets the condition. You still would need to click on such selector to launch fancybox afterwards.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - if I click on the selector, it DOES launch. It's just blank.

Comment: fancybox v1.3.4? ... testing locally? ... do you think you can share a link?

Comment: Ahh, hadn't thought to check the version. It's 1.3.0, unfortunately. I can't update it at the moment. As for a link,I am at work and am using an internal testing server.

Comment: Sorry, hit "enter" too quickly! Anyway, `<dsp:include page="/jsp/product/us/common/accoladeDisplay.jsp"/>` loads the content fine (not in the fancybox), but navigating directly to `"/jsp/product/us/common/accoladeDisplay.jsp` does not (since there are variables that are then not passed to the accoladeDisplay.jsp). So I guess I am wondering how to call fancybox using that `<dsp:include page` method. I suppose I COULD load it into a div with `display;none;` set and then copy it in. That just seems kludgy. Then again, if it works, it works!